# Is it feasible for flash to play a video mp4(h.264) with metadata placed at the end of the file

Tags: flash, video

I'm told that Flash player requires the metadata of the mp4(H.264) be placed at the beginning of the file.

My **question** is: is it possible to use flash to play a video on the http server side, without changing the metadata(metadata still placed at the end of the video). In my case, it's very very difficult for to me change the original mp4 file.

I'm new to flash, so I've no idea whether it's feasible and where can I start. Can I do this with flash and C++, or other things? Does "NetStream appendBytes" can be used in this case? Since the original mp4 is quite large, I hope I can play the video while I'm downloading the video file, instead of playing it after it's totally downloaded.

Thank you so much for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

The video will play, but only after the whole file has finished loading.

You can use [MetaData Mover](http://rndware.info/products/metadata-mover.html) to fix your video file - it doesn't re-compress the video, just moves the data.

What do you mean by 'play video on the server side'? Sending every frame of the video as an image to the user?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In my case, I CAN'T modify the video file. So the MetaData Mover doesn't work for me. I need to do the moving thing in the client side. The video is located in the server side, I(flash) can't modify it.

Comment: I am not sure what you want to do? If you can access files on the server (from your question I assume you can) why can't you re-upload the video file? If you can't access the server, you have no option but let the flash player download the whole video and play it once download has completed.

Comment: Yes, I can't re-upload the video. So my only choice is to the metadata moving in the client side. I hope I can use the NetStream's appendbytes api to the this. For example, I download the metadata atom first, then use the appendbytes to make the metadata is correctly initialized. After that, flash downloads the other part of the video.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `appendBytes` would work, but then, as far as I can tell, this will not cache the information displayed, so rewinding or fast-forwarding would not work (you would have to implement that yourself too). You will likely do a lot of extraneous work, and, very likely will screw up many things by doing them yourself...

I mean, what you are trying to do is like in the joke about a man who was searching for his lost key under the lantern, because it was brighter there instead of searching for the key in the place where he actually lost it. You really should move the metadata or use an existing streaming server (some come as freeware) instead of trying to patch the problem in the way that will cause you to do a lot of extraneous work and, in the end, will probably fail anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. (1) I find it's possible to download the tail of the mp4 file firstly, by using "as3httpclient"'s http range get. (2) I'm curious about whether OSMF can parse the mp4 bytes array and send them to the NetStream(i.e.: has OSMF already done those hard work for me)? Thanks!